# Prove that $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove that $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx$ converges by making the change of variable $u=x^2$, and applying integration by parts to the resulting integral.
>
> Prove the integral does not converge absolutely.(Use the $u$ form.)

$\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx = \int_0^\infty \sin u \frac{1}{2\sqrt u}du = \sin u \sqrt u|_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty \cos u \sqrt udu$.
Then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: it gives a Fresnel integral

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin u}{2\sqrt{u}}du&=\dfrac{-\cos u}{2\sqrt{u}}\bigg|_{u=1}^{u=\infty}-\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos u}{u^{3/2}}du\\
&=\dfrac{\cos 1}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos u}{u^{3/2}}du,
\end{align*}
where 
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\left|\dfrac{\cos u}{u^{3/2}}\right|du\leq\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{u^{3/2}}du<\infty.
\end{align*}
Note that 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1}\sin(x^{2})dx
\end{align*}
exists by the continuity of $x\rightarrow\sin(x^{2})$ on $[0,1]$.

It is not absolutely convergent since
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{|\sin u|}{\sqrt{u}}du&\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n\pi+\pi/6}^{(n+1)\pi-\pi/6}\dfrac{|\sin u|}{\sqrt{u}}du\\
&\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n\pi+\pi/6}^{(n+1)\pi-\pi/6}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}du\\
&\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{n\pi+\pi/6}^{(n+1)\pi-\pi/6}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(n+1)\pi-\pi/6}}du\\
&\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(n+1)\pi-\pi/6}}\\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}